# Problemes in retrieving completed courses

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I'm new on Laravel 6 and build an application for students. The tables of my database look as follows:

$courses
    -program_id
    -title

$projects
    -user_id
    -course_id
    -title
    -completed 
    -comments

I have two users with different rights (Admin and Member). The Admin user can decide if a project is completed or not (checkbox). Each project belongs to a course (course_id).

I have a success.blade.php which looks as follows:

```
@extends('layouts/app')

@section('content')

<div class="row justify-content-center">
    <div class="jumbotron col-8">
        <h4 class="display-4">{{ __('Finished Projects') }}</h4>
        <ol>
        @foreach(Auth::user()->projects as $project)
            @if($project->comments)
                @if($project->completed === 1)

                    <li>{{ $project->title }}</li>

                @endif
            @endif
        @endforeach
        </ol>
        <a href="/home" class="btn btn-info">{{ __('Back')}}</a>
    </div>
</div>
@endsection
```

This file retrieves completed projects, but I would like to retrieve the courses of the completed projects instead. How can I solve this?

My Controller method looks like this:

```
public function success()
    {

        $programs = Program::orderBy('name')->get();
        $courses = Course::orderBy('title')->get();
        $projects = Project::orderBy('title')->get();

        return view('/success', [
            'programs'  => $programs,
            'courses'   => $courses,
            'projects'  => $projects
        ]);
    }
```

Comment: add your controllers for better answers

Answer (score 0):

you can access to desire course with this query for each project that is ***completed***:

```
$course = Course::find($project['course_id']);
```

Comment: Thanks Hossein, but how do I have to handle this in my success.blade.php? I tried to send the new $course variable to the view but got an error "Undefined variable: project"

Comment: @Tianma1970, first of all, add your controllers to your question. then I will tell you how to handle in blade

Answer (score 0):

Using relationships

https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships

```
// From controller you can do 
$courses = Course::whereHas('project', function($q){
   $q->where('completed', true);
})->get();



// Also this way
$completedProjects = Project::where('completed', true)->get();


// Blade view
@foreach($completedProjects as $project)

  @foreach($project->courses as $course)
      {{ $course->title }}
  @endforeach

@endforeach
```

Comment: Thanks Albert Ramos, I tried it but got the following error:     Invalid argument supplied for foreach() (View: /Applications/AMPPS/www/zenit/resources/views/success.blade.php)

Comment: Have you defined the relationships in your Models?

And you have @if($project->completed === 1) but in your migration does not exist this field, where have been declared?

Comment: I have a column 'completed' in my projects table

Comment: Have you defined the relationship? If so $project->courses should work the error you are getting means $project->courses have no items.

Comment: Thank you for your help, now it works! I forgot the relationship in the model